# Setting user passwords via kernel parameter

Tags: systemd, linux-kernel, password, passwd, kernel-parameters

What is the correct syntax to use these bits of information from [systemd manual](https://systemd.io/CREDENTIALS/):

> systemd-sysusers(8) will look for the credentials passwd.hashed-password., **passwd.plaintext-password.** and passwd.shell. to configure the password (either in UNIX hashed form, or plaintext) or shell of system users created. Replace  with the system user of your choice, for example, root.

and

> Credentials can also be passed into a system via the kernel command line, via the **systemd.set_credential=** and systemd.set_credential_binary= kernel command line options (the latter takes Base64 encoded binary data). Note though that any data specified here is visible to all userspace applications (even unprivileged ones) via /proc/cmdline. Typically, this is hence not useful to pass sensitive information, and should be avoided.

I tried adding kernel option:

```
... systemd.set_credential=passwd.plaintext-password.root:123123
```

```
... systemd.set_credential=passwd.plaintext-password.root:'123123'
```

```
... systemd.set_credential=passwd.plaintext-password.root=123123
```

nothing seems to be picked up. adding `debug` doesn't show anything interesting either.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.system-credentials.html says: "only honoured if no root password has been configured before" So two things to check - was the kernel cmdline actually updated (`/proc/cmdline` shows the new value), and was a root password already set?

Comment: Oh that was important be left out from the main doc. The system is in a way that looks like the root have empty password. guess i will have to read source code again... Thank you for pointing that part out